# fifo: Unblock pending open calls

Tags: c, macos, posix, named-pipes, mkfifo

I use a FIFO (named pipe) for IPC. Now process A calls

- `mkfifo(path)`
- `open(path)`

Naturally `open()` will block until the file is written to by process B. Now I need a way to invalidate a FIFO. Therefore I call

- `unlink(path)`

Now I expected that any blocking `open` call would return, but they don't and my process hangs indefinitely.

How can I unblock the `open` call when the FIFO is unlinked?
Do I have to resort to `O_NONBLOCK`?

PS: I tried the suggested write/unlink/close approach to no avail. The `open` call blocks immediately.

```
void invalidate() {
    int fd = open(path, O_WRONLY)
    unlink(path)
    close(fd)
}
```

I think the issue is

> The FIFO must be opened on both ends (reading and writing) before data
>   can be passed. Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end
>   is opened also.

However `invalidate` should work without knowing if the FIFO is currently opened for reading or not.

Comment: Unlinking a file has no effect on processes that already reference the file.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do what you want.

Comment: You can use non-blocking, and the program will have to periodically check if the link still exists.

Comment: I tried nonblocking, but that brings other problems with it, namely I can't distinguish zero byte `write`s to signify the end of a stream.

Comment: If there's nothing to read, `read()` returns `-1` and sets `ERRNO = EWOULDBLOCK`.

Comment: I tried that, but I got very inconsistent results for `EWOULDBLOCK`. Sometimes it would set `EWOULDBLOCK` and return `0`, most of the time it would not even set `EWOULDBLOCK`... idk what's going on here.

Comment: Well, that's the way it's supposed to work. Something's obviously wrong with the way you're coding things, because the answer below should also work and doesn't work for you.

Comment: Well I can't see what could go wrong just calling mkfifo/open/read in order

Comment: The call to `open(path, O_RDONLY)` should return as soon as the other process does `open(path, O_WRONLY)`, or vice versa.

Comment: As soon as I do the `open` when invalidating, that one hangs as well.

Comment: Are you opening in a loop? The previous one should return, then the next one will hang.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. The first open should be hanging when it starts. Then another process opens the FIFO in the other direction, and the first one should unhang.

Comment: Does it work if you DON'T try to invalidate it?

Comment: I think I know what the issue is. For this approach to work, I would need to be aware if the FIFO is currently opened for reading by someone else. "The FIFO must be opened on both ends (reading and writing) before data can be passed. Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also."

Comment: It is not a given that the FIFO has to be opened at the time of invalidation, needs to work for both cases. Updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invalidator should open the FIFO in non-blocking write mode. This way, its call to `open()` won't hang if there are no readers waiting for it. It should then close the FIFO immediately.

Any processes that were waiting in a read-only open will return when the FIFO is opened. Then they'll immediately read EOF.

```
void invalidate() {
    int fd = open(path, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    unlink(path);
    close(fd);
}
```

Comment: I think I figured it out now. I needed a combination of `open` with `O_NONBLOCK` and handling `EINTR` on the other side.

Comment: If the other side is opening for writing, closing the read side will cause it to get a `SIGPIPE` signal when it tries to write.

Comment: I made a small modification by using `O_RDWR` to also unblock any waiting `open(fd, O_WRONLY)` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Open the FIFO for writing, `unlink` it, then close it. This will make process A's `open` succeed, and the resulting FD will immediately be at EOF. (By the way, the `unlink` is unnecessary if you just want to make `open` return, but is still a good idea for cleaning up.)

Comment: I tried writing and closing it, but `open()` still hangs.

Comment: @ErikAigner It works for me. Please edit the code you tried into your question (of both the program that's blocking and the one that's supposed to unblock it).

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: @ErikAigner You don't need to `write` to it at all. You just need to `open` it with `O_WRONLY`.

Comment: Ah yes my fault... I actually did an open here. Wrote the bit from my (faulty) memory. Fixed.

Comment: @ErikAigner For me, as soon as that `open` executes, the first process unblocks. Also, I'm not using `O_NONBLOCK`. And what does the `open` in the second process return for you?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can (nonportably) open a FIFO in `O_RDWR` mode. When you do and hold the FIFO, other openers won't get blocked in their `open` calls (regardless of whether those are readonly or writeonly open calls). Then you can unlink the FIFO while still holding the `O_RDWR` file handle to it.

Example code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(int C, char **V)
{
    int fd;
    if(0>(fd=open(V[1], O_RDWR))) return perror("open"),1;
    if(0>unlink(V[1])) return perror("unlink"),1;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I read that a bit late sry, figured the `O_RDWR` trick out myself in the meantime ^^

Comment: @ErikAigner It semi-works on MacOS too. At least the `O_RDWR` part. But there it seems to only unblock one opener waiting on that fifo. On Linux it unblocks all of them (e.g., say you've got multiple `cat fifo` or `cat </dev/null > fifo`). On Cygwin I get EPERM for the O_RDWR. Could be worked around with two threads I guess.